# Apache Wicket does not load (or display) static image

Tags: wicket

I am currently working my way into wicket and developed a small demo application. Now I want to display a static image in that application (to be more specific, this image should be added to a panel which is then added to the home page).

This is what I have so far:

1) The HTML code for the panel that should hold the image. There is no specific wicket code present, it should only hold an image present in the project structure.

```
<html><body>
  <wicket:panel>
    Just some static text inside the image panel...<br/>
    <img src="test.jpg"></img>
  </wicket:panel>
</body></html>
```

The panel is called ImagePanel and all three files (ImagePanel.java, ImagePanel.html, test.jpg) are located in the same package.

2) The Java code for the ImagePanel - rather short, as there is nothing really to do:

```
public class ImagePanel extends Panel {
    public ImagePanel(String id) {
        super(id);
    }
}
```

3) The HTML code for the homepage:

```
<html><body>
  <div wicket:id="dynamicComponent"></div>
</body></html>
```

4) And the Java code for the homepage:

```
public HomePage() {
    add(new ImagePanel("dynamicComponent"));
}
```

Please note the following: In practice, HomePage.java and ImagePanel.java are located in different OSGi-projects. The code for the HomePage is simplified here, in practice the ImagePanel is located via a service and dynamically added. **This works so far**, I see the static text. But the image is not loaded, I just get this broken-image-thumbnail.

Like I said, all three ImagePanel-related files (.java, .html, the picture) are located in the very same package. I can access the Panel itself from the homepage-project as I can see the static text. But I can't get the image to display.

The Application Server I use is Jetty, started from inside the project that holds the homepage.

**Update:**
I've narrowed the problem to the following:
Everything works fine as long as I only display static text inside of ImagePanel.html. As soon as I want to add the image (even if inside of a wicket:link-tag as suggested below) I end up with the following exception:

```
[qtp401543768-20] WARN org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.WicketObjects - Could not resolve class [plugin.ImagePanel]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: plugin.ImagePanel
```

So without the image the server bundle is able to load the class from the gui bundle and display the static text. With the image I end up with a ClassNotFoundException for the same class.

Find the whole stack trace here: [stack trace](http://pastebin.com/eSU1Fd1W)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, though meanwhile I managed to solve the problem myself. It was not a sole wicket problem but also some difficulties with the OSGi-bundle-setup.

As I mentioned before, the ImagePanel is located in a different OSGi bundle than the HomePage. The problem arised as all Wicket-libraries are located in the HomePage-bundle (I get Linker errors if both bundles use their own libraries). Therefore loading an image in the ImagePanel used classes located in the HomePage-bundle who now couldn't access the image.

I solved the problem by introducing an OSGi-Service in the ImagePanel-bundle that passes all used images as byte arrays to the HomePage-bundle. The HomePage-bundle has now access to all resources and registers them as `SharedResource` with an id given again by the ImagePanel-bundle.

After registration, it is no problem to access the images in the ImagePanel-bundle via `SharedResourceReference`.

Answer (score 4):

In your template, put a  around

```
 <wicket:link>
   <img src="test.jpg"></img>
 </wicket:link>
```

Wicket will rewrite the url so that the image works.

If you have a dynamic Image that you want to load a Package Resource, you use PackageResourceReference.

e.g.

```
add(new Image("myImage", new PackageResourceReference(MyClass.class, "test.jpg"));
```

Comment: I tried that with various locations of the image. Regardless of where I put the image in the project structure (same package as the ImagePanel, default package of the imagepanel-project, same package as the HomePage, default package of the homepage-project), I end up with an exception: `WicketMessage: Exception in rendering component: [TransparentWebMarkupContainer [Component id = wicket_link-2]]`, caused by a NullPointerException somewhere in the depths of wicket. If I try the same, using "/test.jpg" as src instead of "test.jpg", I end up with the same broken image thumbnail as before.

Comment: Give the full stack trace, it might be irrelevant.

Comment: True, the real cause for the exception was hidden in the console logs. I updated the question above.

Comment: I can tell you that ImagePanel is not part of standard wicket. You might be references a ImagePanel somewhere in code and it depends on something you are missing.

Comment: Is your entire namespace plugin.ImagePanel?

Comment: I think you have a problem with your classpath. You are dynamically merging or importing a second project, it's probably not finding the class at runtime. Also, plugin.ImagePanel is a pretty sloppy namespace. It should be com.yourorg.yourproduct.etc.

There is a implicit contract to try and be unique in your namespaces.